# Select rows that contain a range of values while excluding values from other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hitting a small wall with a query here. trying to see if transactions contain type 01 while excluding transactions that contain item 23 or 25.

here's a reprex.

In SQL fiddle

```
create table purchases (
  transaction_id int,
  item int,
  type int,
  customer char(1)
  
);

insert into purchases values (1, 23, 01, "A");
insert into purchases values (1, 25, 01, "A");
insert into purchases values (2, 23, 01, "B");
insert into purchases values (2, 25, 01, "B");
insert into purchases values (2, 1, 01, "B");
insert into purchases values (3, 3, 01, "A");
insert into purchases values (4, 23, 01,"B");
insert into purchases values (4, 25, 01,"B");
insert into purchases values (5, 23, 01,"A");
insert into purchases values (6, 4, 02,"C");
insert into purchases values (7, 9, 03,"C");
```

Here's the query to identify transactions that only have items 23 and 25 but nothing else, it works, (should be transactions, 1,4 & 5).

```
select transaction_id from purchases where item in (23,25)
and transaction_id not in (select transaction_id from purchases where item not in (23,25));
```

However, when I'm struggling to single out the transactions that have type 01 but not items 23 and 25.

I tried this, but it gives out transactions 2 & 3 when it should only be 3 since 2 does contain items 23 & 25.

here's the query I was going with, based on the first one.

```
select * from purchases where type = 1 and transaction_id not in (select transaction_id from purchases where item in (23,25)
and transaction_id not in (select transaction_id from purchases where item not in (23,25)));
```

expected result

```
transaction_id  item    type    customer
      3          3       01        A
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you want to get as a result? Can you attach the expected output?

Comment: Please edit your question and just ask one question.  Do not include queries for other problems.

Comment: added an expected result and there's only one question

Comment: what is logic for your output ? because transaction id 2 same as transaction id 4 .

Comment: I tried this, but it gives out transactions 2 & 3 when it should only be 3 since 2 does contain items 23 & 25. then your expected  result contain onlt txnid 2. Please explain your problem clearly.

Comment: Yes, my bad, apologies, I modified the expected result

Comment: Okay, this makes more sense. Your unmatched expected result made us all delete our answers. However, we assumed you only need to see the transaction ID. Do you need the complete row instead? In that case, if that transaction has more rows, shall they all be shown? Or does the mere transaction ID suffice?

Comment: are you confuse so much first some one answered that but you change your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated question, i'd suggest you use the NOT EXISTS clause like below

```
select * from purchases p1 where not exists
(
select 1 from purchases p2 where p1.transaction_id=p2.transaction_id 
and p2.item in (23,25))
and type=1
```

[fiddle demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d6eb05fbab4c392ad671542c62ebd0da)

Answer (score 0):

You want one row per transaction, so aggregate and `GROUP BY transaction_id`. Then use the `HAVING` clause and `COUNT` conditionally.

```
select transaction_id
from purchases
group by transaction_id
having count(*) filter (where item = 23) = 0
   and count(*) filter (where item = 25) = 0
   and count(*) filter (where type = 1) > 0
order by transaction_id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=520755370f13d41ba35ca12e7eb5277e

If you want to show all rows matching above transaction IDs:

```
select * from purchases where transaction_id in ( <above query> );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option

```
select p.*
from purchases p
join (
       select transaction_id
       from purchases
       group by transaction_id 
       having count(case when item in (25,23) then 1 end)=0
       and    count(case typ when 1 then 1 end)>0
      )x 
on p.transaction_id=x.transaction_id
```

For your sample data:

```
insert into purchases values (1, 23, 01, 'A');
insert into purchases values (1, 25, 01, 'A');
insert into purchases values (2, 23, 01, 'B');
insert into purchases values (2, 25, 01, 'B');
insert into purchases values (2, 1, 01, 'B');
insert into purchases values (3, 3, 01, 'A');
insert into purchases values (4, 23, 01,'B');
insert into purchases values (4, 25, 01,'B');
insert into purchases values (5, 23, 01,'A');
insert into purchases values (6, 4, 02,'C');
insert into purchases values (7, 9, 03,'C');
```

Result:

```
3   3   1   A
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have already changed the expected result in the question several times (while the query itself does not change), so I'm not sure what exactly you want to get.
In any case, you can take [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=525120e10dc1ecbeff13233c3af3770d) example, and using arrays, filtered by distinct sorted elements:
[image: result]